# Mysql table doesn't exits after copied from old EC2 snapshot backup

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have copied old database folder from /snapshot/var/lib/mysql/old to new current mysql location /var/lib/mysql.
After Restart mysql server, can't showing some table, there are only 17 table showing out of 100.
Also set permission of new location.